# Show $U(f,P) > \dfrac{1}{2}$ (Function similar to Dirichlet)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be given as
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
            x &\text{for $x$ rational,} \\
            0 &\text{for $x$ irrational.} \\ 
        \end{cases}
$$

Given any partition $P = \{x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ of $[0,1]$, show $U(f,P)>1/2$.

My hints are to use $M_i = x_i$ and $x_i > \dfrac{x_i + x_{i-1}}{2}$ since $x_i > x_{i-1}$.

This is a homework question, so hints are appreciated rather than a full solution. I'm just not sure where to start.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using partitions of $[0,1]$ into $n$ equal parts, so the endpoints and midpoints are all rational numbers, and since $g(x)=x$ is maximal at right endpoints, and since right endpoints are rationals, you have a way to show $M_i=x_i$. Then by the remark comparing the right endpoint $x_i$ to the midpoint $(x_{i-1}+x_i)/2$ you can finish.

Comment: [Just for fun], if you know that [any subset of $\Bbb Q$ has outer measure zero](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~ryrogers/HW8-solutions.pdf) (i.e. the "length" of $\Bbb Q$ is zero), then you can understand why the function is not Riemann integrable, but is Lebesgue integrable.